# I dont need to use atributes override and virtual when I change code of a method of the same name in a inherited class. Why is that?

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

Im trying to learn Csharp on my own. I read that if I want to change the code of the method textmethod in inherited class Class2, I have to  write override in front of the method in Class2 and virtual in front of the method in base Class1. So I thought that the textmethod below wont work or change without these atributes. But the method still got updated and I get the text of Class2 textmethod if I make instance of Class2, and exactly the same thing happens when I use the override/virtual atributes. Im using .Net 6.0. What am I missing?

```csharp
namespace nn
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class2 class2 = new Class2();
            class2.textmethod();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Class1 
    {
        public  void textmethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello");
        }
    }

    public class Class2 : Class1
    {
        public void textmethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello there");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try declaring the `class2` variable as being type `Class1` (but still having a value referring to an instance of `Class2`), and you'll see the original method being called instead, because you're not overriding it. You should also get a warning advising you to add the `new` modifier on `Class2.textmethod` to make it clear that you're *deliberately* hiding the method rather than overriding it.

Answer (score 2):

As hinted at by Jon Skeet your question boils down to the difference between the `override` and `new` keywords.

Let's see what [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords) has to say about that:

> In C#, a method in a derived class can have the same name as a method in the base class. You can specify how the methods interact by using the `new` and `override` keywords. The `override` modifier extends the base class virtual method, and the `new` modifier hides an accessible base class method.

You might wonder where the `new` might come from as you didn't use that keyword in your method declaration. However the compiler will implicitly have added it for you. Doing so it will also have notified you about it with a compiler warning to explicitly use the `new` keyword.

#### So what's the difference?

When using the same method signature in a child class as in the parent class without specifically using `override` you implicitly create a `new` method with the same name in the child class that *hides* the method it inherits from it's parent class. You therefore end up with two different methods with the same name and signature. One in `Class1` and one in `Class2` and depending on what Type your instance is at runtime it will choose which method to execute. What this means is that when using the following code:

```csharp
Class2 class2 = new Class2();
class2.textmethod();
```

it executes the method specified in `Class2` (as it hides the other `textmethod()` that is declared in `Class1`).
*However* if you were to change your code as follows (notice how we use poly morphism to assign the `Class2` insatance to a variable of type `Class1`):

```csharp
Class1 class2 = new Class2();
class2.textmethod();
```

in this case the original `textmethod()` as declared in `Class1` would be executed. Even though your `class2` object is still of type `Class2` the hidden base method in `Class1` will be executed.

This is where `override` is different. Instead of creating a second `textmethod()` on `Class2` it *overrides* (literally replaces / extends) the method declared in `Class1`. This means it doesn't matter if you cast your `Class2` instance to `Class1` or not, **in either way the `textmethod()` declared in `Class2` would be executed**.

I highly suggest you take a look at the documentation linked above. There are more examples like that which help a lot when diving into the subtle differences of inheritance in c# :)